# holomorphic function on unit disk $D$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, derivatives

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on $D= (\ z:|z|<1)$ and $f$ is an even function 
(i.e. $f(z)=f(-z)$). Show that there is a holomorphic function $g$ on $D$ such that $g(x) = f(\sqrt{x})$ for all positive real numbers $x<1$.

Here is my attempt:
$f$ even $\implies f'$ odd $\implies f''$ even $\implies\cdots \implies f(z) = a_0 + a_2 z^2 + a_4 z^4 + \cdots$

Now let $g(z) = b_0 + b_1 z + b_2 z^2 + \cdots$

Is it simple to put $x$ and $\sqrt{x}$ to $f$ and $g$ respectively such that $g(x) = f(\sqrt{x})$?
How about $a_n$ and $b_n$? Are they equal?

Comment: Yes, are equal(a_2k=b_k). You are right